# MongoDB update subdocument with specific Id independent of it's location

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

We currently store lots of project-related data in a single document as referencing is a lot more painful than nesting. Every entity has it's own Id. Usually we know exactly which entity we're updating and where it is present in the overall document.

But now I have to update an entity type which is nested in lots of different entities and thus is scattered all around the document. I have it's specific Id but I do not know where it's inside my document unless I iterate over my whole model to find out.

Is there a way in MongoDB to say, that it shoud look for a specific Id and do all operations on that level? I know there are positional operators but it's possible that I need to update a document that's nested below multiple arrays.

I could find the entity inside my model when loaded into the backend and then generate a full path with array filters via reflection but that's quite a lot to implement and not very well optimized. If this can be handled by MongoDB itself that'd be great.

Example document:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("649aae77854d7aaafdedc73e"),
    "SomeEntity": {
        "_id": ObjectId("649aae89f5959c68c86d0a3e"),
        "Array": [
            {
                "_id": ObjectId("649aae9e515f2da2b4113714"),
                "FieldToChange": false
            },
            {
                "_id": ObjectId("649aaeb8c1e2c4076e6d6f7a"),
                "FieldToChange": false
            }
        ]
    },
    "Data": [
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("649aaecddd2d05f3aaf5041e"),
            "FieldToChange": false
        },
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("649aaecfec20fbd88a41dc97"),
            "FieldToChange": false
        }
    ]
}
```

The elements below *Array* and *Data* are the same entity type/schema. Now I need to update let's say the one with Id **649aae9e515f2da2b4113714** to have it's *FieldToChange* value set to **true**. Imagine this is stored even deeper maybe even nested in multiple arrays.

Any way to do this the easy way utilizing MongoDB? Or do I have to build around that manually in the backend?

Answer (score 0):

I think for your case it would be best to fetch the whole record and change the value with a script written in some language like JavaScript(Node JS), and after updating it just replace the object with the updated object.

Comment: Well I'm working in an ASP.NET environment. Executing scripts there would be complicated and updating the whole object likely error prone. I guess if there's no native solution I have to utilize my model framework and map all entities efficiently when loading the whole document so I can later quickly get the path to that entity. Just hoped for a more native approach.

Answer (score 0):

A more nested example document:

```json
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "649aae77854d7aaafdedc73e"
  },
  "SomeEntity": {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "649aae89f5959c68c86d0a3e"
    },
    "Array": [
      {
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "649aae9e515f2da2b4113714"
        },
        "Field1": {
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "649aae9e515f2da2b411372b"
          },
          "Field2": {
            "_id": {
              "$oid": "649aae9e515f2da2b4113b2b"
            },
            "FieldToChange": false
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "649aaeb8c1e2c4076e6d6f7a"
        },
        "Field1": {
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "649aae9e515f2da2b41137cb"
          },
          "Field2": {
            "_id": {
              "$oid": "649aae9e515f2da2b41e3b2b"
            },
            "FieldToChange": false
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "Data": [
    {
      "Field1": {
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "649aae9e515f2da2b4c1a72b"
        },
        "FieldToChange": false
      }
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "649aaecfec20fbd88a41dc97"
      },
      "Field1": {
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "649aae9e695f2da2b4c1a72c"
        },
        "FieldToChange": false
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[image: document]

### The solution

As long as you know the schema of the document, I think it should be fine building up queries.

```
db.demo.updateOne({},{$set: {"SomeEntity.Array.$[elem1].Field1.Field2.FieldToChange": true,"Data.$[elem3].Field1.FieldToChange": true}},{arrayFilters: [{ "elem1.Field1.Field2._id": ObjectId("649aae9e695f2da2b4c1a72c")},{ "elem3.Field1._id": ObjectId("649aae9e695f2da2b4c1a72c") }]})
```

properly expanded as:

```
db.demo.updateOne(
  {},
  {
    $set: {
      "SomeEntity.Array.$[elem1].Field1.Field2.FieldToChange": true,
      "Data.$[elem3].Field1.FieldToChange": true
    }
  },
  {
    arrayFilters: [
      { "elem1.Field1.Field2._id": ObjectId("649aae9e695f2da2b4c1a72c") },
      { "elem2.Field1._id": ObjectId("649aae9e695f2da2b4c1a72c") }
    ]
  }
)
```

The first parameter `{}` catches all the documents. - **Query Filter**

The second parameter `{ $set: { ... }}` defines what and where you want to update. - **Update Operations**

The third parameter `{ arrayFilters: ... }` is the conditional statement. The arrayFilters filter out which element got the specified `_id`. Then on that particular element, the second parameter is executed. - **Options**

Here the `arrayFilters` finds the object which contains the Field1 -> Field2 -> FieldToChange._id (in SomeEntity) or Field1 -> FieldToChange._id (in Data), given the value of FieldToChange._id that needs to be modified.

For a given document like below,

```json
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "649aae77854d7aaafdedc73e"
  },
  "A": {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "649aae89f5959c68c86d0a3e"
    },
    "B": [
      {
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "649aae9e515f2da2b4113714"
        },
        "C": {
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "649aae9e515f2da2b411372b"
          },
          "D": {
            "_id": {
              "$oid": "649aae9e515f2da2b4113b2b"
            },
            "X": false,
            "Y": false
          }
        }
      },
...
```

if you only want to update value of X you have to mention only X then you must not mention Y in the query as attributes don't have a unique _id.

```
db.demo.updateOne(
  {},
  {
    $set: {
      "A.B.$[elem1].C.D.X": true,
      "P.$[elem2].Q.X": true
    }
  },
  {
    arrayFilters: [
      { "elem1.Field1.Field2._id": ObjectId("649aae9e695f2da2b4c1a72c") },
      { "elem2.Field1._id": ObjectId("649aae9e695f2da2b4c1a72c") }
    ]
  }
)
```

### Execution

[image: execution]

### Result

[image: result]

### Edit

I modified the query as the pevious one I provided wasn't working for all scenarios. Here firstly keep all possible subdocuments you that can be updated. Then in the query only pass the ones with final attribute you want to be changed (As mentioned above).

Hope this helps

Comment: But in that case I still need to explicitly specify the full path and all array filters. I've been looking for something like `*.fieldToChange` where `_id : 649aae9e515f2da2b4113714` without a full path nor any array filters.

Comment: @SharpShade I've looked around docs and all for hours, and there doesn't seem to be any universal method provided by MongoDB to do so. I suggest make a note of all possible subdocument paths. And then mention the ones with only the attribute you want to be changed. Like if you got X, Y, Z all as `false` in a subdocument, but you only want X to be `true` then just mention the one's with X as `"A.B.$[objectReference].C.D.X": true` in the query. [I've updated my answer a bit as there was some error in previous one]

Comment: This is exactly why relationships in dbs are used

Comment: @M.UsmanKhilji But MongoDB does not offer much for that, at least if you're working with nested data. Relationships only really work on actual documents. I've reworked our MongoDB framework's model wrapper classes so that they generate a full path already when loading the project. This way I can directly generate filters from their path. Works like a charm, yet still requires manual implementation for each case!